# Mixed language web dev environments

Tags: perl, programming-languages, development-environment

I have inherited a broad, ill-designed web portfolio at my job.  Most pages are written in Perl as most of the data ingested, processed, and displayed on the site comes in the form of flat-files which then have to be meticulously regexed and databased in our MySQL and Oracle databases.

As the first IT-trained manager of this environment, I am taking it upon myself to scrub the websites and lay down some structure to the development process.  One of the choices I have been given is to choose whether or not to continue in Perl.  There is substantial in-house talent for Java and PHP is rather easy to learn.  I have considered taking the reins off the developers and letting them choose whatever language they want to use for their pages but that sounds like it might be trouble if the guy who chose PHP gets hit by a bus and no one else can fix it.

As the years go by hiring Perl programmers becomes more and more difficult and the complexity of maintaining legacy Perl code from previous developers whose main focus may have been just getting a page up and running is becoming very resource-consuming.  Another, previous (non-IT) manager was more focused in on quick turnaround and immediate gratification of pages rather than ensuring that it was done right the first time (he has since been promoted outside our branch).

The production server is solaris.  MySQL has most of our data but new projects have begun using Oracle more and more (for GIS data).  Web servers are universally Apache.  We live in an intranet disconnected from the regular internet.  Our development is conducted in an Agile, iterative manner.

Whatever language is chosen to push forward into, there are resources to have the existing development staff re-trained.  No matter what, the data that comes into our environment will have to be regexed to death so perl isn't going away anytime soon.  My question to the community is, what are the pros and cons of the following languages for the above-defined web dev environment: Perl, PHP, Java, Python, and --insert your favorite language here--.  If you had it to do all over again, which language set-up would you have chosen?

**Edits and Clarifications:**
Let me clarify a bit on my original post.  I'm not throwing everything away.  I've been given the opportunity to adjust the course of the ship to what I believe is a better heading.  Even if I chose a new language, the perl code will be around for some time to come.

Hypothetically speaking, if I chose Assembly as my new language (haha) I would have to get the old developers up to speed probably by sending them to some basic assembly classes.  New pages/projects would be in the new language and the old pages/projects would have to play nice with the new pages/projects.  Some might one day be rewritten into the new language, some may never be changed.

What will likely always be in Perl will be the parsing scripts we wrote years ago to sift through and database information from the flat files.  But that's okay because they don't interface with the webpages, they interface with the database.

Thank you all for your input, it has been very very helpful thus far.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems that your problem is more legacy code and informal development methodology than the language per se. So if you already have Perl developers on staff, why not start modernizing your methods and your code base, instead of switching to a new language, and creating an heterogeneous code base.

[Modern Perl](http://www.modernperlbooks.com/) offers a lot in terms of good practices and powerful tools: testing is emphasized, with the [Test::*](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=Test::&mode=dist) modules and [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/), data base interaction can be done through plain [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBI), but also using ORM modules like the excellent [DBIx::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBIx::Class), OO with [Moose](http://www.iinteractive.com/moose) is now on par with more modern languages, [mod_perl](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/mod_perl) gives you access to a lot of power within Apache. There are also quite a few [MVC frameworks](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=mvc&mode=all) for Perl. One that's getting a lot of attention is [Catalyst](http://catalystframework.org).

Invest in a few copies of [Perl Best Practices](http://www.google.com/search?btnI=&q=Perl+Best+Practices+site:oreilly.com), bring in a proper trainer for a few classes on modern development methods, and start changing the culture of your group.

And if you have trouble finding developers that are already proficient in Perl, you can always hire good PHP people and train them, that shouldn't be too difficult. At least their willingness to learn a new language would be a good sign of their flexibility and will to improve.

It is always tempting to blame the state of your code on the language its written in, but in your case I am not sure that is the case. [Lots of big companies](http://www.google.com/search?btnI=&q=companies+using+perl) seem to have no problem managing huge code bases in Perl, the list is long but the main Web companies are all there, along with a number of financial institutions.

Comment: Catalyst is also great for web work that needs to glue legacy bits together.  Things like Catalyst::Controller::WrapCGI and Catalyst::View::PHP are designed specifically to provide this kind of glue.

Answer (score 5):

I would bring in someone who is very good at `Perl`, to at least look at the current design. They would be able to tell you how bad the `Perl` code really is, and what needs to be done to get it into good shape.

At that point I would start considering my options. If the `Perl` code is salvageable, well than great, hire someone proficient in `Perl`. Also train some of your existing staff to help on the existing code-base. If you don't have someone proficient in `Perl` in charge of the `Perl` code, your code-base may become even worse than it already is.

Only if it was in terrible shape, would I consider abandoning it for another language. What that language is, that is something your going to have to think about that yourself.

*p.s. I'm a bit biased, I prefer `Perl`*

Answer (score 1):

If regex is important I would choose a language with good support.

If you would use java, you will not be able to just copy paste your regex code from the perl code because the slashes have to be escaped. So I would vote against java.

I'm not familiar with php enough to know its regex features, but given your choices I would go for python. You can create cleaner code in python.

Would ruby also be an option? It also has good perl like regex support and rails supports agile web development out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

first off let me point out that [MySQL's spatial extensions work with GIS](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/gis-with-mysql.html).

Second, if you have a bunch of Perl programmers that will need tow ork on the new sites then your best bet is to choose something they won't have too much trouble understanding.  The obvious "something" there is PHP.  When I learnt PHP I'd done some Perl years ago and picked up PHP in no time at all.

Switching to something like Java or .Net (or even Ruby on Rails) would be a far more dramatic shift in design.

Plus with Apache servers you already have your environment set up and you can probably stage any development as a mix of Perl and PHP reasonably easily.

As to the last part of your question: what would you do it in if you could do it over again?  To me that's a seprate and basically irrelevant question. The fact is you're not rewinding and starting over, you're just... starting over.  So legacy support, transition, skills development and all those other issues are far more important than any hypothetical question of what you'd choose in a perfect world if all other things were equal.

Love it or hate it, PHP is popular and is going nowhere anytime soon.  Finding skiled people to do it is not too difficult (well, the dificulty is filtering them out from the self-taught cowboy script jockeys who think they can code but can't) and it's not a far step from Web-based Perl.

Answer (score 1):

If your developers are any good, they'll be able to handle anything thrown at them. Deciding what language to use is quite a tricky strategic position, but I recommend you think very carefully before introducing any MORE (i.e. don't).

Unless of course, there is something that you absolutely cannot do (or cannot do sanely) with what you've got.

Answer (score 0):

I think choosing a single language is key and if your database is primarily MySQL, then PHP seems like the obvious choice. It naturally works with your database, it's open source and there is tons of documentation, source code, doesn't require compiling, etc.

People come and go through positions and any website will evolve over time.  If you have the ability to set some guidelines and rules, I would choose something that is forgiving, common-place, and easy(er) to learn.

I'd also suggest writing it down so people in the future don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Any modern language works with mysql, so choosing PHP for mysql support is a silly reason. I'm not saying you shouldn't chose PHP, just that this is not a good reason for doing so.

Comment: mpeters is right, MySQL alone is not a good reason.  You could argue that moving to a more standard LAMP stack would make it easier to find developers, but JAVA programmers also easy to find.  Finding GOOD developers for any language will still be a problem.